# Create list of subclass elements in java generics

Tags: java, generics, generic-list

i saw that those reflection problems are discussed a lot here. Unfotunately i couldnt find any solution for my problem:

I have one abstract class which handles a lot of stuff for the sublcasses

```
public abstract class A{
    public static <T extends A> create(){
        // some factory stuff here
    }
    public static List<....> createMore(){ /// some stuff here}
}
```

The class A is located in a included library of the main project. Now i want to use the methods of A for the sub classes of A:

```
 public class A1 extends A {...}
```

and use it:

```
   A1 mySubclass = A1.create();
   ArrayList<A1> listOfSubclass= A1.createMore();
```

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: Aside from making the generics work, how do you expect a static method on `A` to know how to construct instances of an arbitrary subclass to fill the list?

Comment: Hi Matt, perhaps this could be solved by a type parameter? The challange is in my eyes the library-problem.... i am asking because i cant see any solution yet, but i thought generics / reflection was built for such things

Comment: perhaps this could work: Class.forName("java.util.List<A1>").newInstance();

Comment: That would be rather unnecessary - at that rate, you might as well just perform an unsafe cast: `List<A1> myList = (List<A1>) new ArrayList();`. But my point isn't about creating _lists_, it's about creating instances of the subclass with which to fill the list.

Answer (score 1):

`createMore` is possible:

```
public static <T extends A> List<T> createMore(){
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

`create` is only (correctly) possible if you return `null`:

```
public static <T extends A> T create(){
    return null;
}
```

Without any input, there is no way that that function can decide what to return. And it must match whatever type the caller scope wants at compile time, without knowing what that is.

Comment: but why cant i get the type of the sublcass at runtime... it is callig the function. Perhaps it is possible through reflections. I dont want to implement the same method in lots of classes..